# How do I find the Laplace transform of the function $f(t)=3t$ if $t\le 6$ and $f(t)=18$ if $t>6$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I found the step function: $u(6-t)\times 3(t-6)+18$ where $u(t)$ is the step function, but I do not know how to find the inverse laplace of this. Do I need to change the form of the step function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there are two kinds of step functions.
$$\begin{align}\mathscr{L}[u(t-T)f(t)](s)&=\int_0^{\infty}u(t-T)f(t)e^{-st}dt\\
&=\int_T^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}f(v+T)w^{-s(v+T)}dv\\
&=e^{-sT}\mathscr{L}[f(t+T)](s)\end{align}$$
And then there is
$$\begin{align}\mathscr{L}[u(T-t)f(t)](s)&=\int_0^{\infty}u(T-t)f(t)e^{-st}dt\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt-\int_T^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt\\
&=\mathscr{L}[f(t)](s)-e^{-sT}\mathscr{L}[f(t+T)](s)\end{align}$$
So
$$\begin{align}\mathscr{L}[3(t-6)u(6-t)+18](s)&=3\mathscr{L}[[(t-6)u(6-t)](s)+18\mathscr{L}[1](s)\\
&=3\left\{\frac1{s^2}-\frac6s-e^{-6s}\cdot\frac{1}{s^2}\right\}+18\cdot\frac1s\\
&=\frac3{s^2}\left(1-e^{-6s}\right)\end{align}$$